# Как timedelta перевести в time в excel?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть таблица в котором есть время c типом timedelta
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Когда я сохраняю эту таблицу как excel файл, у меня получается следующий результат:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А мне нужен результат такого типа: `75:12:12`

Я после сохранения подключился к excel файлу и попытался с openpyxl поменят формат столбца, но я не могу поменять `days` на часы. Варианты которые попробовал:

```
for cell in sheet["E"]:
    cell.number_format = "h:mm:ss"
```

Результат в excel `1:20:12`, а должно быть `25:20:12`

```
for cell in sheet["E"]:
    cell.number_format = "d h:mm:ss"
```

Результат в excel `1 1:20:12`, а должно быть `25:20:12`

Comment: В Libre Office Calc такой формат как вам нужен дает шаблон `[HH]:MM:SS`, возможно и для MS Excel подойдет.

Comment: @insolor помогло) спасибо. Напишите как ответ, отмечу правильным)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Формат ячейки для отображения времени без ограничения количества часов по модулю 24 выглядит как `[HH]:MM:SS`. Ниже скриншот с отображением времени в этом формате из Libre Office Calc:

[image: Скриншот]

Answer (score 2):

У `timedelta` есть метод `total_seconds`, а полученные секунды можно превратить в время

Пример:

```
import datetime as DT
import time

def seconds_to_str(seconds: int) -> str:
    hh, mm = divmod(seconds, 3600)
    mm, ss = divmod(mm, 60)
    return "%02d:%02d:%02d" % (hh, mm, ss)

t = DT.datetime.now()
time.sleep(2)
delta = DT.datetime.now() - t

secs = delta.total_seconds()

print(seconds_to_str(secs))
# 00:00:02
```

Comment: Спасибо, тоже хороший вариант

Comment: @Farid, пожалуйста :)